# No serial data received on ESP32

Tags: esp32

I developed a PCB with an ESP32, but I'm not able to upload the code to the ESP even when pressing the boot button. The error message I'm getting is:

**"A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: No serial data received."**

I have already validated the circuit's functionality, and everything is working correctly.

[image: Circuit schematic]

Comment: Could you please detail what exactly you have checked when you 'validated the circuit' and found everything to be working correctly? It would be helpful if you could share your deign file(s) (schematic at least)

Comment: To validate the circuit, I checked all the soldering joints and measured the voltage to ensure that it is reaching where it should, and I also verified the operation of the buttons

I'm new to the platform and I'm looking for how I can send the design files.

Comment: Why is there a 100uH inductor in series with the regulator output? Do you want to make an oscillator?  Try removing C7.

Comment: The idea is to be a second-order low-pass filter to eliminate frequencies greater than 40Hz. I will remove C7 for testing, but this part was simulated to keep the voltage references consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Same baud rate? TX connected to RX and RX connected to TX? Try holding down BOOT and keeping BOOT held down press RESET, then let go of both and try flashing.

If buttons don't work, try bridging the GPIO pin of BOOT to GND then try.

Comment: Yes, I’ve done all of that. The code is uploading on others circuits, just in that one that isn’t uploading…

Comment: @Vinicius1907 you mean same boards as this one or different esp32 models

Comment: What's ID1 doing? Don't you need to connect to either 3.3V or GND, or is it internally pulled up?

Comment: I tried uploading the code to a new board with the same circuit and a new ESP32 (same model), but the same error persisted. However, on other boards with different circuits the code is uploading, so it shouldn't be a problem with the code.

Comment: D1 is an LED to indicate that the board is being powered.